# How to get the username of the current Office 365 user in a shared document?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-365

I am aware that you can use a VBA function to return the currently logged in user's username using e.g. `Environ$("UserName")` but how do I get the office 365 username, especially when using a shared Excel spreadsheet, where some users might be accessing the document via Excel on the Web (with no VBA).

I was wondering if it might be possible to create a dynamic sheet/temporary "view" that automatically changes for every shared user. Say you have a large data set downloaded into excel. Each user wants to only see the entries relevant to them. Currently, users have to select their name from the filter (and hopefully remember to press "See just mine") to create a temporary custom view just for them. Is it even currently possible to automate this?

Comment: Have you tried [Application.UserName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.username)? Microsoft [says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.username) : "The UserName property of the Application object shows the local user name. By comparison, the UserName property of the Profile object shows the logon name".

Comment: It sounds like you want automation in both browser and desktop environments. If you use vba in a .xlsm file then users must use the desktop environment. You could use Typescript for the browser. Linking to this, in case it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75224409/excel-typescript-get-username-or-email-address

Comment: Ah yes, thank you both for the feedback. Application.UserName seems to return the same as Environ$("UserName") i.e. the PC user, not the Office 365 user. Also, and indeed typescript seem to be the preferred solution for both desktop and browser.  I started looking into the solution from stackoverflow but it doesnt quite work. It also brought the realisation that if more than one person opens the same shared file, they would re-filter for everyone according to their name.